# Mongoose update just some fields of an Array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a collection of documents like this:

```
{
 'email': 'daniele@gmail.com',
 'calls':[
          {
           'day'   : {'mm':9, 'dd':4},
           'value' : "AA"
           },
          {
           'day'   : {'mm':9, 'dd':3},
           'value' : "BB"
           },
          {
           'day'   : {'mm':9, 'dd':2},
           'value' : "CC"
           }
         ]
}
```

How can I update just the values of a chosen day with Mongoose?
I need something like:

Update the values of days 2/9 and 3/9 with *XX* and *YY*

```
Users.findOneAndUpdate(
           {
            'email'        : 'daniele@gmail.com',
            'calls.day.mm' : 9,
            'calls.day.dd' : {$in:[2, 3]}
           },
           {
            'calls.$0.mm'  : "XX",
            'calls.$1.mm'  : "YY"
           });
```

The result should be:

```
{
 'email': 'daniele@gmail.com',
 'calls':[
          {
           'day'   : {'mm':9, 'dd':4},
           'value' : "AA"
           },
          {
           'day'   : {'mm':9, 'dd':3},
           'value' : "YY"
           },
          {
           'day'   : {'mm':9, 'dd':2},
           'value' : "XX"
           }
         ]
}
```

Comment: sorry, I edited my question. Is about "updating" rather than projecting

Comment: May be wrong, but i dont think it's possible. Because mongo findAndModify applies query..find document and then sets properties that you specify. In your case you doing smart updates like 'value that match 2 set to X and value that match 3 set to Y', mongo dont care about this..It will just update what you $set...I would suggest to run find..update what you need and save document.

Comment: So I should `find({'email':'daniele@gmail.com'})` the user, scan all the `user.calls.day.dd`, and for each one of them, check if it's `==2 || ==3` .Than modify the call, and at the end do `user.save()`. right?

Comment: Yep.. Find user..Get all his calls values, check and update properties with what you like.

Comment: But again im not 100% sure..Maybe there is a trick how to do it your way.

Comment: Is it possible to make a kind find() on a object returned by a previous find()?  Like  `Users.find( {'email' : 'x@y.z'} ) .then(function(u){ u.find( {'calls.day.dd' : '2'}); });`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Users.update(
    {
    'email': 'daniele@gmail.com',
    'calls.day.mm':9,
        'calls.day.dd':{
            $in:[2,3]
         }
     },{
        $set:{
              "calls.1.value":"XXX",
               "calls.2.value":"YYY"
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

According to above mentioned description as a solution to it please try executing following MongoDB update operation

```
db.users.update(

    {
        calls: {
            $elemMatch: {
                'day.dd': {
                    $in: [2, 3]
                }
            }
        }
    }, {
        $set: {
            'calls.$.value': 'XX'
        }
    }

)
```